# Как прикрутить код из батника в приложение VB?

Tags: visual-basic, bat

Есть несколько batch файлов, функционал значения не имеет.
Для удобства хочу создать маленькое приложение в VB, буквально несколько
кнопок и расписать в нём аналогичный код из этих батников.
Help please!

Comment: `ShellAndWait` позволит запустить любое внешнее приложение из VB.

Answer (score 0):

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("WSCript.shell")
result = oShell.Run("do someThing", 1, True)
if result ... // ваша логика обработки
```

тут мы говорим что то выполнить, 1 - опционально, режим окна выполнения(посмотрите в документации), True - мы говорим что рантайм будет ожидать пока команда выполниться, если поставить false то ваша команда будет отправлена в шел и при этом программа на vb будет исполняться дальше не дожидаясь результата.

[Документация к WshShell Run](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky(v=vs.84).aspx)